# The logo for Ask Different is different from the Ask Different blog

Tags: bug, blog

As said in the title, there is a major difference between the logos in the two links:

- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Different blog](http://apple.blogoverflow.com)

Can we update the Ask Different blog's logo to match the Ask Different logo?

Comment: To be concise: the blog never got the flat styling overhaul that the main site got.